# Why won't this image center on the page?

Tags: html

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code, and why the image doesn't appear centered on the page?

```
<a href="https://LandingPageURL.com">   
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0030/9939/4106/files/Shipping_and_RETURNS-min_1080x.png?v=1527038127" align="middle">
</a>
```

Comment: Aside from superfluous line breaks?

Comment: `align="middle"` is invalid

Comment: I apologise I cannot get the code to format properly.

Comment: this is improper `align="middle"> />`.

Comment: style="text-align:center;" use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to fixing the html syntax and using a valid image url, you'll need to do something like this to center the image:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <a href="https://LandingPageURL.com">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0030/9939/4106/files/Shipping_and_RETURNS- min_1080x.png?v=1527038127">
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. got it sorted. Apologies to all for breaking the rules

Answer (score 2):

Try to center it with `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://LandingPageURL.com">
  <img 
  src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0030/9939/4106/files/Shipping_and_RETURNS-min_1080x.png?v=1527038127" width="200" align="middle">
</a>
```

Or with `display: flex`.

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://LandingPageURL.com">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0030/9939/4106/files/Shipping_and_RETURNS-min_1080x.png?v=1527038127" height="200" align="middle">
</a>
```

Or as joknawe said `text-align: center`.